# Is the clock oscillator shared among the cores of a multicore processor?

Tags: c, multithreading, x86, multiprocessing, multicore

Do they physically share the same clock? Secondly, is the access to the shared memory randomly done, or one core is prioritized over another. For example, considering a 2 core processor, and core 1 and core 2 are trying to access the same memory in the same clock. Would core 1 be allowed to access that shared memory first then core 2 or it is random?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  For one thing, multicore processors are far beyond doing memory access.  They operate on local caches.  Whether there is a priority when both caches need to resynchronize with main memory is surely design-specific.  For one thing, doing burst transfers makes starvation less likely, because you'd only actually use the priority when both bursts started on the same clock cycle.  Another option besides fixed priority and "random" would be round-robin ("random" is hard to implement anyway).

There's only one clock for memory access, even in cases (e.g. TurboBoost or EIST) where the cores and core-local caches may be using independent clocks.

Clock crossing is only one of many complications of the cache circuitry.

Comment: Yes I know about local caches. But lets say, the accessed location is not in the local caches, then who gets to access the shared L2 cache first? Or even with local caches, who gets to modify the shared location first? Because whenever one of them would modify, the cache coherence would invalidate the same location on the other core's cache.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: The cache coherency protocol determines that.  Only one of the caches can be in the "owned" state which allows transition to "modified".  (On MOESI there's also an "exclusive" state but your question excludes that)  If both request transition from "shared" to "owned" at the same time, then see above, it's probably done with round-robin.

Comment: Lets assume both of them are in the shared state, and now in the same clock cycle both of them want to modify, then who gets to do it first? If like you said, there is a round-robin scheme, would that mean that one particular core would always do it before the other deterministically?

Comment: If you have this level of cache collisions, performance is going to be horrendous no matter what priority scheme is implemented.  The more interesting case is when both cores experience a miss on different cache lines.  In that case you could have four memory access in rapid succession (flushing modifications before eviction, then loading the new cache line, both times two cores)

Comment: Obviously this thing is not common. But assume, both of the cores are trying to lock down a mutex, then they would obviously try to access the same location.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Well, whichever one owns the cache line already should win a tie.  And the OS should avoid waking more than one thread waiting on the same mutex, so this is only the busy-wait-before-sleep case we're worrying about.